# Running a flashloan arbitrage contract on Quickswap but I keep getting a 'VirtualMachineError: revert' error with no other details

Tags: uniswap, brownie, swaps, flash-loans, flashbots

I assume that this means the transaction works but the profit margin isn't high enough to pay back the loan. But unlike the Uniswap errors that have an output like "INSUFFICIENT LIQUIDITY" or "INSUFFICIENT OUTPUT AMOUNT" which can easily be traced back to in the UniswapV2Pair.sol contract this one has no such output and therefore I cannot trace it back in the contracts.

The traceback does point to the swap function call in my arbitrage contract but it gives no other info. However, there is no such error in the UniswapV2Pair contract.

Anyone know how to learn more about this error?

TIA

Comment: I have exactly the same error right now. In my case the problem occurs when I try to init Uniswap in  the constructor. However I can not log anything exact. I already deployed a test version on the main net as a test and the Uniswap related function didn't work at all.

Comment: At the end of your flashloan logic, add a require statement that reverts if the balance of the asset you flashloaned is less than the flashloan amont + fee to rule that error out. You should also isolate your flashloan logic into functions that so you easily unit test them and see exactly where the error is. Here is an example for a flashloan that finds arbitrage between Curve and Quickswap: https://github.com/jalbrekt85/Flashloan-Strategy

Comment: Is flashloan fee on quickswap the same as the trading fee?

Comment: When you take out a flashloan with Aave, you must return the full amount of the flashloan plus 0.09% of the amount that was flashloaned. This 0.09% is typically called the flashloan fee

Comment: I'm not getting flashloan from Aave. Getting it from quickswap.

Comment: You cannot take out a flashloan from quickswap. As far as I know, the only app that provides liquidity for flashloans on Polygon is Aave

Comment: according to their docs you can: https://docs.quickswap.exchange/concepts/core-concepts/03-flash-swaps